# Representation of $sl(2,R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am interested in the unique (up to isomorphism) $5$-dimensional representation of the Lie algebra $sl(2,R)$.

I understand that one can choose the module $V_4 = \text{span}\{x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4\}$, but I'd like to work with a more natural module, like a collection of matrices. I suppose this comes down to finding a nice isomorphism of $V_4$ into a nice space.

I believe for each $n \geq 1$, $Sym(n)$, the space of $n \times n$ symmetric matricies is an irreducible $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ via the action $g.v := gvg^t$. I'd like something similar for the group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ or equivalently the Lie algebra $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't make any sense.  How do you multiply a $2\times 2$ matrix by an $n \times n$ matrix if $2\neq n$?

Comment: @Aaron I understand that one cannot multiply a $2 \times 2$ matrix by an $n \times n$ matrix. I was just hoping something similar exists.

Comment: So, I don't know about $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$, where it might be possible to have an irreducible representation that splits when complexified, but $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ has a unique irreducible representation of dimension $n$ for every $n$, and expressing it in terms of polynomials and differential operators is, at the very least, a convenient and easy to remember description.  Is the complaint that this description requires you to specify the action on generators instead of using the natural matrix structure of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$?

Comment: Sort of. The complaint is that I have some calculations involving the orbit of the action of $G=SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ on (a) the highest weight vector or (b) some vector fixed by the max. cpt. subgroup $K=SO(2)$ but I also would like to work at the Lie algebra level.

Comment: So what you really want is a description of the irreps that not only describes them as a irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, but also gives explicitly the action of $SL_2$?

Comment: @nigelvr: There is something with a similar notation: if $V$ is the standard $2$ dimensional representation of $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ then all the other representations are $Sym^n(V)$, the symmetric tensor product of $V$ of order $n$. So you have there $Sym^4(V)$, where $V$ has basis $x$, $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The $5$-dimensional irreducible representation $\rho:\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_5(K)$, with respect to the standard basis $(e,f,h)$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$, can be given as follows:
$$
\rho(e)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\rho(f)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\rho(h)=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In general, the $n$-dimensional irreducible representation $V=\langle v_0,\ldots ,v_{n-1}\rangle$ can be given by the formulas $\rho(h)v_i=(n-1-2i)v_i$, $\rho(e)v_i=(n-i)v_{i-1}$ and $\rho(f)v_i=(i+1)v_{i+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V_n=<v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n>$ be a vector space and  and define the $3$ operators $d,  \hat d $ and  $e$  as follows 
$$
d(v_i) =  v_{i-1}, \hat d(v_i)=(i+1)(n-i)v_{i+1}, e(v_i)=(n-2i) v_i.
$$
Then $V_n$ turns into   an irreducible $sl_2$-module. I hope you may find now the matrix representation  for $V_4$.